# Link to a deleted question in a book

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I've come across a link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145586/what-continuous-integration-tool-is-best-for-a-c-project) in *Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development* by Jeff Langr (2013, The Pragmatic Programmers, LLC). The context looks as follows:

> [...] You'll find some good discussion on appropriate CI tools at StackOverflow.<sup>8</sup>

where the 8-th footnote contains the link.

*In general*, how should we proceed in such situation?

- In case of some books commonly perceived as somehow valuable, perhaps such questions should be undeleted and marked with historical lock?
- In case of fresh books (i.e. published at the time when SO rules already classified such questions as inappropriate), should we notify the author/publisher that linking to such content is not a good practice?
- Do nothing, books are for old people, we don't care.

Comment: Im perplexed as to why a book would hardcode a link to an SO question. O_o

Comment: If option 2 is chosen it would appear they're not very active on so ([user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/723912/jlangr)) but do appear more active on [twitter](https://twitter.com/jlangr?lang=en-gb)

Comment: Pretty typical about recommendation questions, what was "lost" is the conclusion that *any* CI tool is useful.  Vote totals merely reflect their market share.  A pragmatic book reader can't go wrong so it doesn't matter that it was lost.  Heh.

Comment: I get that *Do nothing, books are for old people, we don't care.* is a joke but can we make it a non ageist joke?  I am young and I love to read.

Comment: You're just old at heart @NathanOliver. :p

Comment: @Magisch: Why would a book link to anything on the Internet?

Comment: The publisher should have used their rights under the SO content license to host the content on a server they control, or failing that, linked to an archived version on archive.org in addition to SO itself.

Comment: One of the reasons why questions like that are closed and deleted is because they become obsolete so quickly. I'm generally a pretty-strong anti-deletionist, but I don't see any value in bringing this one back. If someone gets a 404 and ends up searching the web instead, they're better off than they would have been otherwise.

Comment: @hobbs This. The answers are mostly from 2008 and 2009; they were already significantly outdated when the book was published, and will only get worse with time.

Comment: For the same reason link-only answers are frowned upon on SO, link-only book sections are a really, bad idea too. Basically you have no control and this will result in disaster sooner or later.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm going to go *way* out on a limb here and guess that the relevant section of the book was not "link-only".

Comment: I would say, one can notice the author if someone wants to do it but the SO community is generally not obliged to notify anyone when content on So is changed. So if volunteers want to do it, go ahead.

Comment: @JeremyBanks You would be surprised.  I did a technical review for a book a couple years ago that had more links to useful content than actual printed content, it was almost completely useless in an off-line setting.  We're not talking about an ebook or a PDF, but an actual printed book.

Comment: Computer books go outdated as fast as (no, faster than) Stack Overflow questions do. Let them go their way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's undelete and historically lock it.

The question isn't suitable for the site. The answers weren't great, and are probably outdated. There's no arguing that it should be reopened, and that will be clearly communicated by the Historical Lock notice. However, we should avoid breaking links **when we know that people are going to continue to use them**. That's clearly the case here, when they're printed in a reference book that many people are reading.

This isn't just a question that people are stumbling across from Google, or by links on old stale forum threads. This is a book that is still being purchased. Perhaps the author made a poor choice, but we can make a good one. Let's be good internet citizens and keep the link alive.

Comment: This also seems a valid point, I'll wait and see how the votes will go :)

Comment: "However, we should avoid breaking links when we know that people are going to continue to use them" <- so basically, we shouldn't delete anything ever under any circumstance?  We're basically putting ourselves at the mercy of 3rd parties by insisting that we keep around garbage just because they link to it.

Comment: @cimmanon Don't be disingenuous. I am drawing a distinction between random links scattered around the internet (frequently in old abandoned threads that few will see, or wikis that could be updated with newer resources), and links that are in a printed nonupdatable publication which is still selling in reasonable numbers. The harm from bad content, due to the broken window effect or what have you, manifests when it is easily visible to regular visitors. You are aware that very few questions are referenced anywhere, and the exposure of historically locked questions is minimal. Explain the harm.

Comment: I don't see the benefit in this particular case.  It's essentially a recommendation question, which is the worst kind of content to histolock because the content is often outdated within months.  A question that contains a bunch of outdated information and dead links seems about as useful as deleting the content outright.  By keeping the content there, you're giving the illusion that it's still useful or relevant, when often times it is not.

Answer (score 20):

Personally I don't think a post being linked to from a book should change our calculus on whether or not to delete vs. histo-lock content; I would see the view count or question score as better indicators of whether the question is worthy of the histo-lock.

Anybody who includes a URL in a publication that can't be easily updated (e.g. a book or journal article) runs the risk of that link going stale sometime in the future (and apparently links in such publications do rot [at an alarming rate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/51875/41886)), so URLs in that medium should probably be used sparingly and only to support a point made in the text of the publication. This nicely parallels the case with Stack Overflow questions and answers: any link in a post might go stale sometime down the road, so links should only be used to support a point that's already been made in the post.

Luckily for the book authors, there's always [the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150409004145/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145586/what-continuous-integration-tool-is-best-for-a-c-project).

Comment: So, I'm going to write a book, composed of a series of url with  incremental ids.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think about contacting the author/publisher? Perhaps someone from SO staff could point them in the right direction?

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.” - Kind of universal truth in that one.